# Breaking a block in adventure mode and replacing it directly with a 'canplaceon' tagged block

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

Well, I am working on a puzzle map. And the player gets an item which can be used to break certain blocks. the thing is when you break a block it does not have any tags or whatsoever. So my question is: How can I make it so that when a block gets broken it gets replaced with the same block but with tags like: canbreak/canplaceon, etc?

Answer (score 1):

you'd have to `entitydata` the resulting item. For that you run the `entitydata` command on all items without a tag and then tag those items. Here is an example for stone:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=item,tag=!processed] add stone {Item:{id:"minecraft:stone"}}
/execute @e[type=item,tag=stone] ~ ~ ~ /entitydata @s[type=item,tag=!processed] {Item:{tag:{CanPlaceOn:["minecraft:dirt","minecraft:stone"]}}}
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=item,tag=stone] add processed
```

this way the resulting item entity will be changed instantly and will have the CanPlaceOn Tag already when the player picks it up.

Comment: Is it also possible to get the given item a colored name? or just a name?

Comment: Or.. Can you replace items in the players inventory? :p

Comment: Coloured name? Sure, also any other NBT. Replace item? Yes, but if you want it in the same spot, you need a lot of commands to detect the amount and slot.

Comment: And how would you do that? :p

Comment: that is a whole nother question. please create a new one (or even better, search for it first) if you want help with that.